# SignalR core JWT authentication not working

Tags: .net-core, jwt, signalr, signalr-hub

I'm trying to authenticate with JWT in .NET Core 2.2 with SignalR. I don't get an error message that it doesn't work on either the server or the client-side. I have set breakpoints on the server-side where the authentication is supposed to happen. Does anyone have any idea why it's not working? The JWT is built with an asymmetric signature algorithm.

This is how I generate the JWT:

```
var utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;  

            using (RSA privateRsa = RSA.Create())  
            {  
                privateRsa.FromXmlFile(Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~"),  
                    "Keys",  
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PrivateKey"]
                ));  
                var privateKey = new RsaSecurityKey(privateRsa);  
                SigningCredentials signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(privateKey, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256);  


                var claims = new Claim[]  
                {  
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.ID.ToString()),  
                    //new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.NameId, user.FullName),
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),  
                    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iat, utcNow.ToString())  
                };  

                var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(  
                    signingCredentials: signingCredentials,  
                    claims: claims,  
                    notBefore: utcNow,  
                    expires: utcNow.AddMonths(12),  
                    audience: "https://pacsonweb.com",  
                    issuer: "PACSonWEB3 App"  
                );  

                return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);
```

This is how i'm authenticating on the server side :

```
RsaSecurityKey signingKey = new RsaSecurityKey(publicRsa);  

        services.AddAuthentication(options =>  
        {  
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;  
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;  
        }).AddJwtBearer(config =>  
        {  
            config.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;  
            config.SaveToken = true;  
            config.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()  
            {  
                IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,  
                ValidateAudience = true,  
                ValidAudience = this.Configuration["Tokens:Audience"],  
                ValidateIssuer = true,  
                ValidIssuer = this.Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],  
                ValidateLifetime = true,  
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true  
            };
        });
```

This is how I send the JWT with SignalR on the client side:

```
hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(hubUrl, (opts) =>
        {
            opts.AccessTokenProvider = () => Globals.GetJWTToken();
            opts.HttpMessageHandlerFactory = (message) =>
            {
                if (message is HttpClientHandler clientHandler)
                {
                    // bypass SSL certificate
                    clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback += CheckCertificate;
                    clientHandler.CheckCertificateRevocationList = false;
                }
                return message;
            };
        }).Build();
```